# Is throwing an Exceptions or returning Option better for "Find by ID" methods?

Tags: scala

Let's say, I have a method that takes a `List` and finds one element based on the id. It could be that this element might not be present! What should be done in this case? Should we throw an `Exception` or rather deal with `Option` types?

```
def myMethod(entries: List[MyType], id: Long): MyType = {
  val result = entries.collect { case entry if entry.id == id => entry }
  assert(...check if result is not empty....)
  result.head
}
```

My argument is that the statement `assert(....)`, I explicitly force an `IllegalStateException` that the caller has to deal with. Is this a good practice? or Should I rather return an `Option[MyType]` and let the caller deal with the situation? What do you guys think?

Comment: I think "opinion-based", and varying by framework/library. That being said, returning Option usually makes for more idiomatic composability in Scala .. on the other hand consider that they are not mutually exclusive (compare, eg. `First` and `FirstOrDefault`).

Comment: In FP world it's discouraged to throw exceptions, which is a kind of side effect. However if you consider a situation when a list is missing some id as "exceptional" (due to code or configuration error), then use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with the standard patterns of the programming language.

In Scala it is common to use `Try` and `Option` instead of throwing Exceptions.
Also to use the rich standard library that already comes with the method you have described `find`.

## idiomatic scala

```
scala> List(1,2,3).find(_ == 5)
//res0: Option[Int] = None

scala> List(1,2,3).find(_ == 2)
res1: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

## Example with Exception wrapped in `Try`

```
// needed to make sure that MyType has an method `id`
trait MyType { def id : Long }


def myFindWithException[A <: MyType](entries: List[A], id: Long): Try[A] = Try{
  entries
    .find(_.id == id)
    .getOrElse( throw new Exception("Your Text here") )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's really exceptional for an element not to be present in a `List`, so in this case I would go for returning an `Option`.
If you consider it to be a precondition for calling `myMethod(list, id)` that there is an element with a corresponding id in `list`, you could throw an `Exception`.

Comment: This is definitely not a pre-condition as it can be seen! Even I do not agree with this assert(...) as it just leaves the caller of this method with an un-checked exception!